# Data not getting displayed in Silverlight project

Tags: silverlight

I am given with a silverlight project. Its partially done and DB Connections are given. I just copied the project into my system. I have started debugging. Then, the front end UI is getting displayed but with no data. Dropdown are there, Grid headers etc..but data not getting retrieved from Database. I could not find why is that exactly as i am new to silverlight.

Can anyone help me out..

Comment: Really hard to help with no information given. How do you load your data from DB? Do you have some service? How do you try to display it on the UI?

Comment: @Zabavsky I mean is that related to web.config or some installations etc... something like that. Because data not getting displayed only in my system as recently i have copied that project to my system. On debugging UI got displayed. Its fine. But data not binding..

Comment: It could be any number of issues, but without more details it will be difficult to diagnose. I would start by debugging the server side code and see if it actually fetches any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. At last found date in incorrect format. System date and code written for date format are not matching.